# 3D-Plot optimization results for varying parameter values

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

Before starting, FYI: This is a question related to [3D Plot the result of local Minimize with varying parameter values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191686/3d-plot-the-result-of-local-minimize-with-varying-parameter-values)

Consider my objective function, $objF$:

```
objF=1/(2 s^2) (2 (-k + s) (d^2 - d s - ((d - s) ((-1 + d) k^2 r + c (2 d^2 (-1 + q) + k^2 (-1 + 2 q) r + 2 d s) - s (-2 (-1 + d) d + d s + s^2)) (-1 + t))/(2 s^2) - d t + s t) - (d^3 - 2 d^2 s + d s^2 - ((d - s)^2 (6 c d^2 (-1 + q) + 3 k^2 (-1 + d + c (-1 + 2 q)) r + 6 d (-1 + c + d) s - 4 d s^2 - 2 s^3) (-1 + t))/(6 s^2) - d^2 t + 2 d s t - s^2 t)/r)
```

with parameter values: $t=0.2$, $s=2$, $d=0.8$ and $k < d$, $k \geq 0$, $0 \leq r \leq 1$, $0 \leq c \leq 1$, and $q \geq 1$.

I'm trying to maximize the above objective function with respect to $r$ and $k$.

Eventually, I would like to `Plot3D` each of the optimal values of $objF$, $r$, and $k$ against $c$ and $q$.

My mathematica codes are as follows.

First, for $objF$:

```
max = MaxValue[{objF, k < d, k >= 0, 0 <= d <= 1, 2 d < s, 0 <= r <= 1, 0 <= t <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1, q >= 1}, {k, r}]
Plot3D[max, {c, 0, 1}, {q, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {c, q, max}]
```

Second, for $r$:

```
maxR = Last@Last@Maximize[{objF, k < d, k >= 0, 0 <= d <= 1, 2 d < s, 0 <= r <= 1, 0 <= t <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1, q >= 1}, {k, r}]
Plot3D[r/.maxR, {c, 0, 1}, {q, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {c, q, r}]
```

Third, for $k$:

```
maxK = First@Last@Maximize[{objF, k < d, k >= 0, 0 <= d <= 1, 2 d < s, 0 <= r <= 1, 0 <= t <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1, q >= 1}, {k, r}]
Plot3D[k/.maxK, {c, 0, 1}, {q, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {c, q, k}]
```

These are not working properly. Can anyone help please? Thank you!

Comment: It is necessary to determine the parameters `d, s, t` at the beginning of the code.

Comment: @Alex Trounev: I have corrected the silly mistake of forgetting to specify the value of t,s,d. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: There is $1/r$ and $r$ starts with `r = 0`. Therefore, with these parameters, the maximum=`ComplexInfinity` is reached at `r = 0`.

Comment: @Alex Trounev: Thanks! My followup question is, how do we know that the numerator of the term with $\frac{1}{r}$ is positive? If it is negative, then the maximum is reached at `r=1`, no?

Comment: Yes, this is also possible, $r= 1$ included. But in 3D it looks awful.

Comment: @Alex Trounev: Can you please instruct me how to construct 3D out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the numerical method, but because of the singularity $1/r$, I have to trim $r$, for example, start with $r=r0, r0=10^{-3}$. This value is selected to avoid messages.

```
Block[{d = .8, s = 2, t = .2, r0 = 10^-3}, 
 objF = 1/(2 s^2) (2 (-k + s) (d^2 - 
        d s - ((d - s) ((-1 + d) k^2 r + 
             c (2 d^2 (-1 + q) + k^2 (-1 + 2 q) r + 2 d s) - 
             s (-2 (-1 + d) d + d s + s^2)) (-1 + t))/(2 s^2) - d t + 
        s t) - (d^3 - 2 d^2 s + 
        d s^2 - ((d - s)^2 (6 c d^2 (-1 + q) + 
             3 k^2 (-1 + d + c (-1 + 2 q)) r + 6 d (-1 + c + d) s - 
             4 d s^2 - 2 s^3) (-1 + t))/(6 s^2) - d^2 t + 2 d s t - 
        s^2 t)/r); 
 max = Flatten[
   Table[{c, q, 
     MaxValue[{objF, 0 <= k < d, r0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {c, 0, 
     1, .1}, {q, 1, 2, .1}], 1]; 
 maxk = Flatten[
   Table[{c, q, 
     k /. Last@
       Maximize[{objF, 0 <= k < d, r0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {c, 0, 
     1, .1}, {q, 1, 2, .1}], 1]; 
 maxr = Flatten[
   Table[{c, q, 
     r /. Last@
       Maximize[{objF, 0 <= k < d, r0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {c, 0, 
     1, .1}, {q, 1, 2, .1}], 1];]
{ListPlot3D[max, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "max"}], 
 ListPlot3D[maxk, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "maxK"}], 
 ListPlot3D[maxr, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "maxR"}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: I have tried your solution with another objective function, which however generates some errors. I have create a new post for this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200232/3d-plot-for-optimization-with-varying-parameter-values Can you please help once more?

Comment: Hello Alex, I am applying your solution in an extended case where the objective function now takes three different expressions depending on the constraints. May I ask for your help once more? I really really appreciate! My new post is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201823/3d-plot-multiple-maximization-results-in-one-same-diagram