# 3D Plot multiple maximization results in one same diagram

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

My objective function, $f(r,k;s,d)$, takes three different expressions, denoted by $f^1$, $f^2$, and $f^3$, respecitvely, depending on the conditions for the arguments and parameters as follows:

$f^1(r,k;s,d) = \frac{3 s \left(d^2-k^2 r\right)+k^2 r (3 d+k r)-6 d s^2+3 s^3}{6 s^2}$ when $0\leq d\leq 1,s\geq 2 d,0\leq k<d,0\leq r\leq 1$,

$f^2(r,k;s,d) = \frac{d^3+3 d^2 (k (r-1)-s)+3 d \left(k^2 ((r-3) r+1)+2 k r s-2 (r-1) s^2\right)+k^3 (r ((r-1) r+3)-1)-3 k^2 r^2 s+3 (r-1) s^3}{6 (r-1) s^2}$ when $0\leq d\leq 1,s\geq 2 d,d\leq k\leq s,0\leq r<\frac{d}{k}$,

$f^3(r,k;s,d) = \frac{d^3+3 d^2 k r+3 d r \left(k^2 (r-1)-2 s^2\right)+k^3 (r-1)^2 r+3 r s^3}{6 r s^2}$ when $0\leq d\leq 1,s\geq 2 d,d\leq k\leq s,\frac{d}{k}\leq r\leq 1$.

My ultimate goal is to find the optimal value of $r$ and $k$ at which the objective function $f$ gets maximized over all the three cases. It has turned out that working with analytical solutions is quite daunting. So I'm working with numerical simulations limited to the parameter values of $d \in [0,1]$ and $s \in [0,2]$.

My strategy is as follows:

First, construct a code that solves the maximization problem for each of the above three functions and computes the maximized value of the function and the corresponding optimal $r$ and $k$ (Obviously, these will be a function of $s$ and $d$.) For instance, for the first case of $f^1$, let me denote them by $f^{1*}$, $r^{1*}$, and $k^{1*}$; and the same for the cases of $f^2$ and $f^3$.

Second, using `Plot3D`, plot $f^{1*}$, $f^{2*}$, and $f^{3*}$ in one same diagram against $d \in [0,1]$ and $s \in [0,2]$; similarly, plot $r^{1*}$, $r^{2*}$, and $r^{3*}$ in one same diagram against $d \in [0,1]$ and $s \in [0,2]$, and plot $k^{1*}$, $k^{2*}$, and $k^{3*}$ in one same diagram against $d \in [0,1]$ and $s \in [0,2]$.

Lastly, since the first diagram allows comparing $f^{1*}$, $f^{2*}$, and $f^{3*}$, I can get the maximum value of the objective function $f$, and by looking at the second and third diagrams, I can get the corresponding optimal $r$ and $k$, which are what I'm ultimately looking for.

My Mathematica code for doing this is as follows (which is an extension of Alex Trounev's answer in [3D-Plot optimization results for varying parameter values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197842/3d-plot-optimization-results-for-varying-parameter-values)):

```
Block[{t = 0}, f1 = (k^2 r (3 d + k r) + 3 (d^2 - k^2 r) s - 6 d s^2 + 3 s^3)/(6 s^2); max1 = Flatten[Table[{d, s, MaxValue[{f1, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, 0 <= k < d, 0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1]; maxk1 = Flatten[Table[{d, s, k /. Last@Maximize[{f1, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, 0 <= k < d, 0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1]; maxr1 = Flatten[Table[{d, s, r /. Last@Maximize[{f1, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, 0 <= k < d, 0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1];] Block[{t = 0}, f2 = 1/(6 (-1 + r) s^2) (d^3 + k^3 (-1 + r (3 + (-1 + r) r)) + 3 d^2 (k (-1 + r) - s) - 3 k^2 r^2 s + 3 (-1 + r) s^3 + 3 d (k^2 (1 + (-3 + r) r) + 2 k r s - 2 (-1 + r) s^2)); max2 = Flatten[Table[{d, s, MaxValue[{f2, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1]; maxk2 = Flatten[Table[{d, s, k /. Last@Maximize[{f2, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1]; maxr2 = Flatten[Table[{d, s, r /. Last@Maximize[{f2, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1];] Block[{t = 0}, f3 = (d^3 + 3 d^2 k r + k^3 (-1 + r)^2 r + 3 r s^3 + 3 d r (k^2 (-1 + r) - 2 s^2))/(6 r s^2); max3 = Flatten[Table[{d, s, MaxValue[{f3, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, d/k <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1]; maxk3 = Flatten[Table[{d, s, k /. Last@Maximize[{f3, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, d/k <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1]; maxr3 = Flatten[Table[{d, s, r /. Last@Maximize[{f3, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, d/k <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 0, 2, .1}], 1];] {ListPlot3D[max1, max2, max3, AxesLabel -> {"d", "s", "V"}], ListPlot3D[maxk1, maxk2, maxk3, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"d", "s", "k"}], ListPlot3D[maxr1, maxr2, maxr3, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"d", "s", "r"}]}
```

(In the code, you can simply by-pass the meaning of $t=0$.)

When this code is run, I get a list of error messages. Can anyone help? Thanks so much, in advance!

Comment: When s = 0 you will divide by zero.  You have some semicolons missing between statements (mathematica will interpret this to mean you want to multiply).  `ListPlot3D` takes all the data in a single argument, not a sequence, i.e. `ListPlot3D[{a,b,c}]` not `ListPlot3D[a, b, c]`.

Comment: Thanks, wxffles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both variables `d, s` must be separated from 0. Then there are no messages.

```
Block[{t = 0, d0 = 10^-6, s0 = 10^-6}, 
 f1 = (k^2 r (3 d + k r) + 3 (d^2 - k^2 r) s - 6 d s^2 + 
     3 s^3)/(6 s^2); 
 max1 = Flatten[
   Table[{d, s, 
     MaxValue[{f1, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, 0 <= k < d, 
       0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, d0, 1, .1}, {s, s0, 2, .1}], 1];
 maxk1 = Flatten[
   Table[{d, s, 
     k /. Last@
       Maximize[{f1, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, 0 <= k < d, 
         0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, d0, 1, .1}, {s, s0, 2, .1}], 1]; 
 maxr1 = Flatten[
   Table[{d, s, 
     r /. Last@
       Maximize[{f1, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, 0 <= k < d, 
         0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, d0, 1, .1}, {s, s0, 2, .1}], 1];]

Block[{t = 0, d0 = 10^-6, s0 = 10^-6}, 
 f2 = 1/(6 (-1 + r) s^2) (d^3 + k^3 (-1 + r (3 + (-1 + r) r)) + 
     3 d^2 (k (-1 + r) - s) - 3 k^2 r^2 s + 3 (-1 + r) s^3 + 
     3 d (k^2 (1 + (-3 + r) r) + 2 k r s - 2 (-1 + r) s^2)); 
 max2 = Flatten[
   Table[{d, s, 
     MaxValue[{f2, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 
       0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]}, {d, d0, 1, .1}, {s, s0, 2, .1}], 1]; 
 maxk2 = Flatten[
   Table[{d, s, 
     k /. Last@
       Maximize[{f2, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 
         0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]}, {d, d0, 1, .1}, {s, s0, 2, .1}], 1];
  maxr2 = Flatten[
   Table[{d, s, 
     r /. Last@
       Maximize[{f2, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 
         0 <= r < d/k}, {k, r}]}, {d, d0, 1, .1}, {s, s0, 2, .1}], 1];]

Block[{t = 0, d0 = 10^-6, s0 = 10^-6}, 
 f3 = (d^3 + 3 d^2 k r + k^3 (-1 + r)^2 r + 3 r s^3 + 
     3 d r (k^2 (-1 + r) - 2 s^2))/(6 r s^2); 
 max3 = Flatten[
   Table[{d, s, 
     MaxValue[{f3, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 
       d/k <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, d0, 1, .1}, {s, s0, 2, .1}], 1]; 
 maxk3 = Flatten[
   Table[{d, s, 
     k /. Last@
       Maximize[{f3, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 
         d/k <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, d0, 1, .1}, {s, s0, 2, .1}], 
   1]; maxr3 = 
  Flatten[Table[{d, s, 
     r /. Last@
       Maximize[{f3, 0 <= d <= 1, s >= 2 d, d <= k <= s, 
         d/k <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {d, d0, 1, .1}, {s, s0, 2, .1}], 
   1];] 

{ListPlot3D[{max1, max2, max3}, AxesLabel -> {"d", "s", "V"}], 
 ListPlot3D[{maxk1, maxk2, maxk3}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"d", "s", "k"}], 
 ListPlot3D[{maxr1, maxr2, maxr3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"d", "s", "r"}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thanks, Alex, as always! It was very helpful, this time as well!!

Comment: @ppp you're welcome!

Comment: May I ask you a followup question? I'm trying to add one more complication. Regarding the conditions in the second `Block[]` for $f_2$, I would like to make a slight change as follows: $k=d$ if $r=0$, and $d <k\leq s$ if $0 < r < \frac{d}{k}$. For this, I replaced `d <= k <= s, 0 <= r < d/k` by `If[r == 0, k = d, d < k <= s]`. And I don't get a result. I also tried `k==d` instead of `k=d`. It gives some result, which however doesn't seem right. Can you please help me once more? I really appreciate!

Comment: @ppp A special case would be better to allocate a separate block, and then combine the results.

Comment: Yes, it is working! Thanks so much, Alex!! You are so great!